# Not able to upload files on AWS server root folder getting 'file permission error'

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload a google webmaster file to aws root folder with Filezilla. I'm getting the following error

[image: error while uploading file]

and my root folder permission is set to 755. But still i'm getting file permission error.

[image: folder permission]

Comment: test it with 777 permission, and see if it works. if it did, then it's a simple file system permission mismatch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not authorized to access this directory. Ask your administrator/Root user to run this command.

**sudo chown -R USER_NAME:USER_NAME FOLDER_PATH**

**USER_NAME**: Your username

**FOLDER_PATH**: Folder path

I have also faced the same issue earlier so I sorted it like this.

Comment: You are most Welcome ! Enjoy ! :)